# Insight about the number of solutions to the congruence $x^2 + y^2 ≡ 1$ mod p

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Show the number of solutions to $x^2 + y^2 \equiv 1 \mathrm{\;mod \;p}$ is equal to the number of solutions to $x^2 = a$ times the number of solutions to $x^2 = b$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$, where $a + b = 1$.
I am told that the transition is trivial, but would appreciate if someone could explain it to me in more detail.

Comment: I believe you should add summation on $a$.

Comment: How would you go about doing so ? @IvanKaznacheyeu

Comment: Let consider any solution of $x^2+y^2\equiv 1 \pmod p$. For this solution $x^2$ is equal to some number $a$ and $y^2$ is equal to some number $b$, such that $a+b=1$. If $x^2=a$ has $m$ solutions $x_1,x_2,...,x_m$ and $y^2=b$ has $n$ solutions $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$. Then every pair $x_i,y_j$ is solution of $x^2+y^2=1$. Number of solutions with given $x^2=a$ is equal $mn$. But we can take different values of $a$, so we need to make summation on $a$. Let mark number of solutions $x^2=a$ as $M(a)$. Then total number of solutions of $x^2+y^2=1$ is $N=\sum_a M(a)\cdot M(1-a)$.